# Sending notification with javafx without stage

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, notifications

You can send a desktop notification with JavaFx like this (requires jdk 8u20 or later):

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
//        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Button notifyButton = new Button("Notify");
        notifyButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            Notifications.create().title("Test").text("Test Notification!").showInformation();
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(notifyButton, 100, 50));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But this way you have to create a main window (stage), is it possible to avoid this? I am looking for a way to send notification like using zenity in bash: most of the code is non-gui, but uses some gui elements for informing or interacting with user in a very basic fashion.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  A stage is just a window.  You cannot show any kind of UI in a desktop windowing system without windows.  In these [zenity screenshots](http://www.howtogeek.com/107537/how-to-make-simple-graphical-shell-scripts-with-zenity-on-linux/), all of the dialogs are windows.  You do not need a third party controlsfx library to show a UI dialog (though it may help).  You can just [init the primary stage style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initStyle-javafx.stage.StageStyle-) and populate the stage to show a dialog.

Comment: With zenity you can do whatever you want without even touching gui (in bash), and only pop up windows when necessary. With Javafx, it's not  obvious to me how you can even receive command line args. The problem is you can't do much in main() except launch(args).

Comment: See [Application::getParameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--) for command line parameter retrieval in JavaFX applications. See [Platform::setImplicitExit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-) to run a JavaFX application in the background when no windows are shown.  See [stage::show, stage::hide and stage::showAndWait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) for different ways to show and hide stages on demand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the ControlsFX notifications require a existing stage.  You can create a hidden utility stage.  Try something like this.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFXPanel();
        notifier("Good!", "It's working now!");
    }

    private static void notifier(String pTitle, String pMessage) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    Stage owner = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                    StackPane root = new StackPane();
                    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: TRANSPARENT");
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1, 1);
                    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    owner.setScene(scene);
                    owner.setWidth(1);
                    owner.setHeight(1);
                    owner.toBack();
                    owner.show();
                    Notifications.create().title(pTitle).text(pMessage).showInformation();
                }
        );
    }
}
```

`new JFXPanel()` initializes the JavaFX thread without having to extend `Application`. You have to call this before any calls to `Platform.runLater()` otherwise you will get a thread exception. You only need to call it once for the whole application though.  Honestly it is probably better to create your own notification stage and display it directly.  Create a stage like above and put your own contents.  You can probably reuse some of the styling from the ControlsFX source.

Comment: I got this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Owner window must not be null`, code is here: http://ideone.com/WTi0Ka

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with ControlsFX. https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issue/200/showing-notifications-without-a-owner They decided to not fix it.  Work arounds are to either create a transparent stage or to place the stage at an x-y that is offscreen.

Comment: It's runLater, and there should be a closing }.

Comment: And a ; is missing. But other than these typos, everything indeed works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I edit your answer a little bit? I will just post the complete java file here.

Comment: I can't believe they closed that bug. The whole reason I need a notification is to tell the user that the app is running in the tray bar. _sigh_. This code doesn't completely work for me. It creates empty entries in the task bar.

Comment: won't it leak memory on creating new stage for each notification?

Comment: @sergeych The example is a simplified proof of concept.  But it should be a simple matter of reusing the same stage if you are going to display multiple notifications.